# Creating a typescript class implementing an interface

Tags: typescript

I would like to implement an interface, but I am having hard time getting the syntax right.

Interface I would like to implement

```
interface Test {
  [name : string] : (source : string) => void;
}
```

If I understood this right, the interface is basically an object with strings as keys and functions as values.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit : I get several errors, "incorrect implementation of interface", "index signature is missing", etc,

Playground example : 
[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Test1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(source%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestClass2%20implements%20Test1%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getLastName(source%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22test%22)%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestClass3%20implements%20Test1%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22getName%22%3A%20(source%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22test%22)%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)

I did not implement the interface, it is from a sdk

Comment: So, what did you try, and what error did you get? And what is this interface supposed to represent? Why did you define it if you don't know how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the index signature to the class:

```
interface Test {
    [name: string]: (source: string) => void;

}

class TestClass implements Test {
    [name: string]: (source: string) => void; // Add this
    getLastName(source: string) {
        console.log("test"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a class can implement an interface such as this one.

This is more of a "typed object" interface.

You can type an object to specify that it should have a string as keys and a function taking a string and returning nothing as values.

Like so:

```
let myObj: Test = {
    test: (source: string) => { console.log('function returning void'); }
};
```